# Sql blind Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, testing

I have c# form based web application. When i am scanning the the application through Acunetix web scanner its giving me the a blind sql injection on a add module section. The report generated by the Acunteix is

```
POST (multipart) input ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlRecommendoffer was set to -87
POST /
```

This ddlRecommendoffer is a drop down list and gets the values from database and when i am storing the form in the database i am getting the value of this drop down as

```
 ddlRecommendoffer.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

DDL Value  should ideally be an int(Id of the Row from the database)

i am using a store procedure with  parameters to insert it into database  which should stop Sql injection but then why is it showing me BLIND SQL INJECTION on this field..

Comment: Chances to show your stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

A SQL injection is called blind when there is no direct feedback from the injection attempt, e.g., when the result of the SQL statement is not returned back to the user.

Your application may still be vulnerable although you’re using a stored procedure if it builds the query with the parameters dynamically:

```
Create Procedure sp_EmployeeSelect
  @EmployeeName NVarchar(100)
AS
  Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
  SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM tblEmployees 
    WHERE EmployeeName LIKE ''%' + @EmployeeName + '%'''
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
GO
```

Here you can still inject SQL via *EmployeeName* as it’s not properly formatted/escaped.

However, using the parameterized form would be secure:

```
Create Procedure sp_EmployeeSelect
  @EmployeeName NVarchar(100)
AS
  Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
  Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000)
  SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM tblEmployees 
    WHERE EmployeeName LIKE ''%'' + @EmployeeName + ''%'''
  SET @ParamDefinition = '@EmployeeName NVarchar(100)'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition,
    @EmployeeName
GO
```

Comment: Hi Gumbo , all my procedures are using parametrized quires and i am not building the queries dynamically

Comment: @user1457334 Then it may be a false positive. Doesn’t it give you a proof of concept?

Comment: I mentioned to my testers that it can be  false positive... but they are saying... Testing tool is generating the following Request header   -------AcunetixBoundary_ESSTPIYHPH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlRecommendoffer"
3*333-997+1-2    and the Response is a error custom error page of my app

Comment: @user1457334 Well, since it’s your server: any chance to see a more detailed error message, maybe an error trace?

Comment: Does your custom error page return a 500 HTTP status? It appears that it is passing the value 1 via the calculation 3*333-997+1-2 which will find out if it is processed by the database server but doesn't detect the fact that an error is triggered.